# C++ Can someone help me optimize this code?

Tags: c++, signal-processing

I am trying to perform a circular convolution on a large boundary can someone help me optimize this to run faster? I am trying to cconv to signal with a large number of samples. downsampling is not an option.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> /* clock_t, clock, CLOCKS_PER_SEC */
#include <math.h> /* sqrt */
using namespace std;

void fillarray(double* x, int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        x[i] = i + 1;
}

void circcon(double* x, double* y, double* u, int N)
{
    for (int m = 0; m < N; ++m)
        for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n) {
            if ((m - n) < 0)
                u[m] += x[n] * y[m - n + N];
            else
                u[m] += x[n] * y[m - n];
        }
}

int main(void)
{
    int N = 447650;
    double* x = new double[N];
    double* y = new double[N];
    double* u = new double[N];
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();

    fillarray(x, N);
    fillarray(y, N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        u[i] = 0.0;

    circcon(x, y, u, N);
    t = clock() - t;
    printf("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n", t, ((float)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not really I am actually working on an assignment. my problem is that the pulse sample rate is high and downsampling results in losing data. I am trying to find a way to speed up my nested loops. so far it takes (1122.361000 seconds). for one cconv!!!

Comment: I need to do 1000 of them which will take me ages !! any idea where to look??

Comment: I think you'll get better results if you replace the inner loop with two sub-loops, from 0 to m, and m+1 to n, performing the appropriate calculation in each sub-loop and eliminating the `if` statement completely. The `if` statement is going to mess up modern CPU's branch prediction.

Comment: You should also turn on optimizations when compiling your code.  Did you do that, or are you debugging an unoptimized, "debug build"?  Also, any `O(n * n)` solution where `n` is large will almost certainly be slow.  You should throw out that "solution" right away, until you've exhausted all ways of rearranging your calculations, use one or more data structures or algorithm, etc.

Comment: You need to perform the operation in frequency space. Google "Convolution Theorem" and "Fast Fourier transform" (and get yourself a book on signal processing while you're at it)

Comment: not sure what you are referring to but I am compiling it g++ main.cpp then running the executable. It would be awesome if you can point to what you are referring to.

Comment: @SayfBenFraj -- So you are not aware of the `-O2` or `-O3` compiler switches (there are even more)?  What is the exact command line you're using to compile your code?

Comment: I am performing it in the frequency domain. this is just a test case to see if the circular convoluation is working. this will be applited to the fftw_complex type and will be in the frequency domain.

Comment: I am using cmd on my windows g++ main.cpp, then just executing the exe @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @eerorikaI am familiar with the theorem, and this is how a circular convolution is performed. I am trying to match what MATLAB do for cconv any pointers?

Comment: @SayfBenFraj Then you better get to the command line and add those options.  Your timings are meaningless until you set those compiler options.  Once you set those options, then and only then will your timing information will be relevant.  Even though your algorithm is slow, possibly the optimization switches would make the speed acceptable, but that is impossible to tell until you are able to compile your code with those options.

Comment: Thank you @ PaulMcKenzie  i am testing it now :)

Comment: Also, if it were me, I would never have even tried to time this, knowing the function will loop `N*N` times, unless there is a chance that the code was actually "fast enough".  So were you hoping the code was fast enough, or just knew it was going to be slow anyway?  If it is the former, then you should have tried the optimization switches and hope for the best.

Comment: @SayfBenFraj *this*  - as in your `circcon` function - *is how convolution is performed* ***in time domain***. Both the input signal and the IR are big, and your algorithm is O(n*n) complexity, so if you must use time domain for some reason, then there's not much you can do. Maybe you could achieve some gains using SIMD intrinsics if that is an option.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are completely right. My only option to improve this might be to use omp parallel or collapse the two for loops. The code is meant to mimic Matlab cconv. I probably have a queue but I am not sure that would work.

Comment: @eerorika i am trying to find the peak resulting from a circular corrolation of two signals. my thought process was to flipstream and conj one of them then circular convolve bothe signals in the frequency domain the ifft back and find the peak loc.

Comment: @SayfBenFraj Sorry, but my DSP knowledge is very basic. All I know is that point wise multiplication of the frequency domain signal is convolution in the time domain (the convolution theorem). I have no idea what convolution of a frequency domain signal does.  But if that's what you must do, I guess there's nothing preventing you from calculating the FFT of the input signal whether it is time or frequency domain.

Comment: @eerorika thank you for the help.

Comment: MATLAB is really, really good at doing this sort of thing.  To do the same with C++ likely will require SIMD and threading, or going whole-hog and doing GPU (which ought to beat MATLAB at its own game).

Comment: @SayfBenFraj MATLAB is in the business of doing these things.  They have some of the best programmers working for them in the industry that understands these things much more than a solo programmer trying to do N*N loops.  That's the way it is, sorry to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on by how much you need to improve the performance...

First I would make `y` of size `2N` with second part being copy of the first so that instead of the if statement `if((m-n) < 0) u[m] += x[n]*y[m-n+N]; else u[m] += x[n]*y[m-n];` one can write simply `u[m] += x[n]*y[m-n+N];`.

Then, you could try making it multi-threaded, seek tutorials on that. There are plenty.

Consider using SIMD instructions, though I believe that nowadays compilers use them automatically in simple enough cases.

However, the best solution would be to find an implementation of FFT (fast fourier transform). Then you could complete the convolution in O(n log n) operations instead of O(n^2). I just googled and found a library that does it:

http://www.alglib.net/fasttransforms/convolution.php

Edit: if you have matlab - they have had FFT for ages.